# How can I use MultiSnapRecyclerView by TakuSemba in Android Fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, retrofit

I have include  implementation 'com.github.takusemba:multisnaprecyclerview:1.3.3' in my app Gradle file.

I'm trying to create multiSnapRecyclerView for Movies(Running/Upcoming) and Events so I need 3 recyclerView. I'm using 2 Adapters one for the Movies and another for the event.

The following the code that I have included in onSuccess method of the Fragment and also using the retrofit for this as I'm getting the info from the API

```
HomePageTestAdapter firstAdapter = new HomePageTestAdapter(mContext, list);
LinearLayoutManager firstManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mContext, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
MultiSnapRecyclerView firstRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.first_recycler_view);
firstRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(firstManager);
firstRecyclerView.setAdapter(firstAdapter);

HomePageTestAdapter secondAdapter = new HomePageTestAdapter(mContext, list);
MultiSnapRecyclerView secondRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.second_recycler_view);
LinearLayoutManager secondManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mContext, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
secondRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(secondManager);
secondRecyclerView.setAdapter(secondAdapter);

EventTestHomeAdapter thirdAdapter = new EventTestHomeAdapter(mContext.getApplicationContext(), list);
MultiSnapRecyclerView thirdRecyclerView =  view.findViewById(R.id.third_recycler_view);
LinearLayoutManager thirdManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mContext.getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
thirdRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(thirdManager);
thirdRecyclerView.setAdapter(thirdAdapter);
```

List contains the response of the retrofit api call containing List of Movies and Events.

Help me in how to use the same in fragment. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

use `getActivity()` instead of context.

> ```
> @Override
> public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
>                          Bundle savedInstanceState) {
> View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recycler, container, false);
> MultiSnapRecyclerView firstRecyclerView=view.findViewById(R.id.first_recycler_view);
> LinearLayoutManager firstManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivty(),LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
> recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
> HomePageTestAdapter firstAdapter = new HomePageTestAdapter(getActivity(), list);
> firstRecyclerView.setAdapter(firstAdapter);
> ```

```
public class SharedData{
    public static List<PojoClassName> list= new ArrayList<>();

   insert getter and setter method
}
```

after that where you get data from server you can set the list data like this :

> SharedData.setList(response);

and in retrieving data like this : list

> SharedData.getList();

after that you access list in fragment onCreateView()

Comment: Hi, even after using getActivity() it did not work. list cannot be accessed in the in onCreateView() as list is a response of API call in retrofit.

Comment: I have already created the Model Class where getter and setter methods are their. Now I have called a user defined function Load() inside the onCreateView() . Inside the Load() method RestService is called(Basically API call is done here) . In the OnSuccess method, the list of type model class, Im getting the response after that the above mentioned code is their.

Comment: Hey pl click on this paste.ofcode.org/MVuDdTA4xYZY49LKy9TVpp you can find the code( need to 
 append  https://  before the paste.ofcode.org)

Comment: Its not giving the error, its only displaying the home_test_page.xml file ie. Running movies,Upcoming Movies and Events. Even the adapter class not being called. But when I use with Activity it works absolutely fine.